# OR Statement performing all evaluations

Tags: c++, c++11

In an OR evaluation does C++ continue evaluating past the first TRUE it finds?

ie.

```
if(Foo() || Bar())
{
  //..
}
```

If Foo() returns true will Bar() be skipped completely or will it also run that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators && and || perform so called short-circuit evaluation, which means they do not evaluate the second operand if the result is known after evaluating the first. So no, `Bar()` would not be evaluated in this case.

EDIT: That's the built-in functionality, as other people said. If they are overloaded, you obviously can't rely on it anymore.

Comment: I believe a notable exception is if the || or && operators are overloaded.

Comment: Note:  if a class provides an `operator||` or `operator&&` the short-circuiting behavior does NOT apply.  (Generally recommended *NOT* providing that kind of operator overloading.)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Hopefully no one would try to confuse people like that :)

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `||` operator short-circuits.  The left-hand expression is guaranteed to be evaluated first, and if the result is `true`, the right-hand expression is not evaluated.

The `&&` operator is the opposite.  The left-hand expression is evaluated first and if it evaluates to `false` then the right-hand expression is not evaluated.

---

Note that this does not hold for user-defined `operator||` and `operator&&` overloads.  Those do not provide short-circuit evaluation.  Both sides of the expression will be evaluated.

Comment: "Both sides of the expression will be evaluated."  which is why you should not normally overload these operators.